# Power Shell CSV conversion

Tags: powershell, csv

Hi I am trying to export a text file to csv format in Powershell but facing some alignment issue.data not coming properly.

Input text

```
clexec.py "top -d1|grep Swap"
NVA-0055-Prod-N08:Swap: 48G Total, 1428K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N01:Swap: 48G Total, 332K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N04:Swap: 48G Total, 169M Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N05:Swap: 48G Total, 884K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N02:Swap: 48G Total, 4236K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N06:Swap: 48G Total, 132K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N07:Swap: 48G Total, 92K Used, 48G Free
NVA-0055-Prod-N03:Swap: 48G Total, 712K Used, 48G Free
```

I am using below below command

```
$a= import-csv 'C:\Users\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.txt' -Delimiter 't' -Header 'Name','Total','used','free'
$a | export-csv csvfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My output coming like below

[image]

after correcting th delimiter part I am getting all the data in a single column but I need it to split among the columns Total,used and free

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop the initial line from the file,
you may read content as text and skip the first line before `ConvertFrom-Csv`

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.txt' | Select-Object -Skip 1|
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header Name,Total,used,free |
    Export-Csv csvfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Just in case there is no tab but space(s) like above sample, you could use

```
$Data = Get-Content '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.txt' |Select-Object -skip 1| ForEach-Object{
    $Name,$Total,$used,$free = ($_ -split('\s+'))[0,1,3,5]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
       Name = $Name
       Total= $Total
       used = $used
       free = $free
    }
}
$Data
$Data | Export-Csv '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$Data | Export-Excel  '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.xlsx' -AutoSize -Show
```

and thereby strip off the label from each value:

```
Name                    Total used  free
----                    ----- ----  ----
NVA-0055-Prod-N08:Swap: 48G   1428K 48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N01:Swap: 48G   332K  48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N04:Swap: 48G   169M  48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N05:Swap: 48G   884K  48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N02:Swap: 48G   4236K 48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N06:Swap: 48G   132K  48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N07:Swap: 48G   92K   48G
NVA-0055-Prod-N03:Swap: 48G   712K  48G
```

When using [Export-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) you'll directly get an xlsx file

[image]

**EDIT: as mentioned in the comment here a variant using a RegEx to separate the elements**
See the RegEx live https://regex101.com/r/GFXpXw/1 with a missing used value

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\15\SO_53322626_2.ps1

$RE = "^(?<Name>[^ ]+) (?<Total>\d+[KMG]) Total(, (?<used>\d+[KMG]) Used)?, (?<free>\d+[KMG])"

$Data = Get-Content '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.txt' |Select-Object -skip 1| ForEach-Object{
    if ($_ -match $RE){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
           Name = $Matches.Name
           Total= $Matches.Total
           used = $Matches.used
           free = $Matches.free
        }
    } else {Write-Host ("{0} didn't match RegEx" -f $_)}
}
$Data
$Data | Export-Csv '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.csv' -NoTypeInformation
#$Data | Export-Excel  '.\PDC_AVERE_SWAP_OP.xlsx' -AutoSize
```

Comment: what if for some cases the used column is not there ,will the free column data moved to used column or it will come as blank ?

Comment: If there is no delimiter to separate data as intended the values will slide left, this could be avoided using a more complex regular expression using lookaheads and named capture groups (assuming you are using the 2nd script)

Comment: See changed answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `-Delimiter 't'`. It literally means that letter `t` is the delimiter character. Most likely you mean the tab character, which in Powershell is backtick-t: `` `t ``.

Answer (score 1):

use  "`t" instead of "t" as Delimeter and instead using **Export-CSV** you can use the following code,

```
 "Name,Total,used,free" | Set-Content csvfile.csv

 $a  |   %{ Write-Output "$($_.Name),$($_.Total),$($_.free),$($_.free)"  |  out-file csvfile.csv -Encoding  ascii  -Append  -Force   }
```

Comment: Please edit the answer and explain why `out-file` would be better than `export-csv`.

Comment: Usually Out-File you will give you more flexibility and more control over it. Consider a scenario, you have several different variables in a script and you need to select some properties from multiple variables and export the output to CSV.in that case you cannot use Export-CSV. Now coming to your question, sometime Export-CSV does not work as expected as in your case (don't know exact reason ) then we can use Out-File to get more control over it.@vonPryz